# Preencher <select> no mesmo arquivo através de outro <select> a partir de dados do BD

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tenho um form onde contém um `option select` função,  alimentado pela consulta do BD. e Na tela fica aparecendo apenas o 1º `option select` só vai aparecer o segundo `option select` depois que selecionar o 1º.

Ao selecionar uma opção ele mostra um outro `option select` tipo com o resultado dessa 1ª seleção, e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Só que tenho um problema essa minha resolução está em dois arquivos, o `index.php`, onde está a seleção de função e o jquery, e um outro arquivo `listaFuncoes.php` onde está a seleção do resultado tipo.

E gostaria de uma solução para essa resolução ficar em apenas um arquivo, ou ficar visível os 2 `option select`, tem essa possibilidade?

`index.php`:

```
<?php
require './conexao.php';
?>
<DOCTYPE>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Atualizando combos com jquery</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#funcao').change(function () {
                        $('#tipo').load('listaFuncoes.php?funcao=' + $('#funcao').val());
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Atualizando combos com jquery</h1>
            <label>Função:</label>
            <select name="funcao" id="funcao">
                <option value="">selecione</option>
                <?php
                $rs = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM funcao ORDER BY nome");
                for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($rs); $i++) {
                    $linha_funcao = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?= $linha_funcao[0] ?>"><?php echo $linha_funcao[1] ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <div id="tipo">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`listaFuncoes.php`:

```
<?php
require './conexao.php';

$id_estado = $_GET['funcao'];

$rs = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT DISTINCT tp.idfuncao, tpd.id ,tpd.descricao "
        . "FROM tipos_prova tp "
        . "INNER JOIN tipos_prova_descricao tpd ON tpd.idDescricao = tp.desctipoprova "
        . "WHERE tp.idfuncao = '$id_estado' "
        . "ORDER BY tpd.descricao");

echo "<label>tipo: </label><select name='tipo'>";
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($rs); $i++) {
    $linha_funcao = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $linha_funcao[0] ?>"><?php echo $linha_funcao[2] ?></option>
    <?php
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Como está utilizando AJAX, é bem melhor que a página requisitada esteja num arquivo separado, como está fazendo. Juntar tudo num mesmo arquivo é complicar as coisas sem necessidade.

Comment: Entendi, deixa eu explicar, talvez não tenha expressado bem. ao abrir a pagina ele mostra apenas o `1º option`, e ao selecionar a opção é que aparece o `2º option` com o resultado. Gostaria que ficasse mostrando os 2 pelo menos.

Comment: Tente adicionando `.change()` no evento: `$('#funcao').change(function () {
                        $('#tipo').load('listaFuncoes.php?funcao=' + $('#funcao').val());
                    }).change();`

Comment: Vlw, funcionou perfeitamente, era isso que queria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui adicionando `.change()` no evento:

Antes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#funcao').change(function () {
                        $('#tipo').load('listaFuncoes.php?funcao=' + $('#funcao').val());
                    });
                });
```

Depois:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#funcao').change(function () {
                        $('#tipo').load('listaFuncoes.php?funcao=' + $('#funcao').val());
                    }).change();
                });
```